# How do I centre UITextField cursor after user input consistently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` that I want to centre all content (text, cursor) at all times. Is this possible in iOS 7? My current initialisation of the view is shown below.

```
self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
self.textField.delegate = self;
[self.textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
self.textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
self.textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
self.textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter some text", @"The placeholder text to use for this input field");
```

My requirement for this is that when I click in the `UITextField`, the placeholder text should disappear, and show the cursor in the middle of the `UITextField`.

Currently, this seems to be intermittently positioned either in the middle of the text field or on the left of the text field irrelevant of where I click. Anybody got any suggestions as to how I can solve this or is it a known issue in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating you UITextField in you Storyboard you should not initialise and alloc it in code.

You need to use you Textfield delegates to accomplish this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField.delegate = self;
    [self.textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    self.textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    [self.textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.textField.placeholder = @"Enter some text";
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //this removes your placeholder when textField get tapped
    self.textField.placeholder = nil;
    //this sets your cursor to the middle
    self.textField.text = @" ";
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.textField.placeholder = @"The placeholder text to use for this input field";
}
```

This surely does the trick.. Please accept the answer if it helps.

**UPDATE**

With code below when user press backspace the cursor will not align the text to the left.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *proposedNewString = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"propose: %@", proposedNewString);

    if ([proposedNewString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        textField.text = [@" " stringByAppendingString:textField.text];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works great for almost all cases, only problem is the user is able to press backspace which would then align the text to the left again.

Comment: I think any other edge cases are probably a limitation of this, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: There is no limitation for this one. I was curious so I did a bit of coding. Check my updated answer :)